# Append a string to variable during array creation

Tags: arrays, tcl

I'm attempting to create a very simple array in TCL but I can't figure out the syntax to make it append text to a variable in an assignment.  Here is what I am trying to do:

```
set var1 "some text"
set var2 "other text"
array set arrValues { 
    1    $var1 + _text
    2    $var2 + _text
    3    $var1 + _different_text
    4    $var1 + _different_text
}
```

How do I tell it that it should treat `$var1 + _text` as the data that needs to get inserted without needing to make another variable outside of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to substitute the variables, you can't use `{braces}` to declare the array elements:

```
$ tclsh
% set var1 "some text"
some text
% set var2 "other text"
other text
% array set arrValues {1 ${var1}_text 2 ${var2}_text 3 ${var1}_different_text 4 ${var2}_different_text}
% parray arrValues
arrValues(1) = ${var1}_text
arrValues(2) = ${var2}_text
arrValues(3) = ${var1}_different_text
arrValues(4) = ${var2}_different_text
% array set arrValues [list 1 ${var1}_text 2 ${var2}_text 3 ${var1}_different_text 4 ${var2}_different_text]
% parray arrValues
arrValues(1) = some text_text
arrValues(2) = other text_text
arrValues(3) = some text_different_text
arrValues(4) = other text_different_text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just join the string together... But so it knows where the variable name ends, put it in braces ${var1}_text... And so your array values get evaluated, put them in quotes instead of braces, or use [list a b c]
(Please excuse lack of format - answering from my phone)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest robust way is probably to use the `list` command to construct the thing to use with `array set`:

```
set var1 "some text"
set var2 "other text"
array set arrValues [list \
    1    "$var1 + _text" \
    2    "$var2 + _text" \
    3    "$var1 + _different_text" \
    4    "$var1 + _different_text"
]
```

That's assuming that you want just the variable substituted. (`"${var1}_text"` might be more suitable for your specific case; you can build the value to insert using any Tcl substitutions you want.) However, in this case I'd *actually* just do this instead:

```
set var1 "some text"
set var2 "other text"
set arrValues(1) "$var1 + _text"
set arrValues(2) "$var2 + _text"
set arrValues(3) "$var1 + _different_text"
set arrValues(4) "$var1 + _different_text"
```

It's shorter. The `array set` command only really becomes useful when you are using literal dictionaries as the source of what to set, or when you're taking a serialized value generated elsewhere entirely (e.g., from an `array get` in another context).